# How I can i audioread all files in a folder

Tags: matlab

I have a folder with files named like this: "speaker1_001.wav". It goes From 001 to speaker1_020. How can I do a for loop to "audioread" all the files and storing the value in variables with different names?

This is what I got, but I only obtain one variable instead of 20.

```
mypath = fullfile('TrainVoices', 'speaker1');
for idx = 1:20
  filename = fullfile(mypath, sprintf('speaker1_%d.wav', idx));
  nameSpeaker = sprintf('speaker1_%d', idx);
  [nameSpeaker, fs] = audioread(filename);
end
```

Comment: I am confused with your question! First tell me if the given code snippet **worked?** If yes, then are you asking whether **is it possible** to work with different file names which might not have similar trend in name, like this one `speaker1_%d.wav`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you try to dinamically create the name of the output variable `nameSpeaker` with the instruction `nameSpeaker = sprintf('speaker1_%d', idx);` in order to use it as output variable in the call to `audioread`.

This is not correct since you actually assign the string created with `sprintf` to the variable `nameSpeaker` rather then "change" the name of it.

Also, you have to manage the "zeros" included in the filename.

A part from this error (which can be fixed), in general it is not a good practice to use dinamically created variable.

A possible solution could be to store the `wav data` in a struct which allows to dinamically create the name of the field.

Moreover, since according to the code you've posted you know in advance the `path` and the root name of the inout files, you can create the complete filename by simply appending the different strings rather than using `fullfile`

In the following you can find a possible implementaton of the proposed solution.

The output will be a struct named `nameSpeaker` with a set of fields named `speaker1_1`, `speaker1_2`, `speaker1_3` ... etc after the name of the input file in which, for semplicity the "zeros"have been removed.

Each of this fields is a struct with the field: `data` and `fs` containing the data of the wav file.

For example:

the data of `speaker1_001.wav` arfe stored in the struct

```
nameSpeaker.speaker1_1.data
nameSpeaker.speaker1_1.fa
```

the data of `speaker1_002.wav` arfe stored in the struct

```
nameSpeaker.speaker1_2.data
nameSpeaker.speaker1_2.fs
```

and so on.

```
% Defina the path
mypath='TrainVoices\speaker1'
% Define the file root name
f_root_name='speaker1_'
% Define the extension of the input file\
ext='.wav'
% Loop over the input filess
for idx = 1:20
   %& add the proper number of "0" to tjhe filename
   if(idx <= 9)
      f_name=[f_root_name '00' num2str(idx)]
   else
      f_name=[f_root_name '0' num2str(idx)]
   end
   % Build the filename
   filename=fullfile(mypath,[f_name ext])
   % Read the wav file
   [data,fs] = audioread(filename);
   % Store the wav file data in a struct
   nameSpeaker.([f_root_name num2str(idx)]).data=data;
   nameSpeaker.([f_root_name num2str(idx)]).fs=fs;
end
```

You can make access to the data by simply specify the "idx" of the file.

For example, to make access to the data of `speaker1_001.wav`, you can simply define the file "idx" and then build the names of the fields accordingly:

```
file_idx=3
data=nameSpeaker.([f_root_name num2str(file_idx)]).data
fs=nameSpeaker.([f_root_name num2str(file_idx)]).fs
```